# How to pass Text parameter to the function in the loop?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Hi I'm stuck I need to pass the Status into the Apply() function. But when I put Apply("+ Status +"); into the for loop it doesn't seem to work. But if Status is equal to some number it works. Please help. Here is my code.

Status is equal to "Complete, Uncomplete".

```
function querySuccess(tx, results, Type, Status, Amount, Years){
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var display = "";

    display +="<table>";
    display +="<tr>";
    display +="<td>First Year Rate</td>";
    display +="<td>Apply Now</td>";
    display +="</tr>";

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
    display +="<tr>";
    display +="<td>"+ results.rows.item(i).first_year+"</td>";
    display +="<td><input type'button' onClick='Apply();' value='Apply'/></td>";
    display +="</tr>";
    }
    display +="</table>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Apply(\""+ Status +"\");`. The escaped quotes tells JS that there is a text, otherwise it thinks there are some variables.

You can use single-quotes `Apply('"+ Status +"');`, but this need some modifications in your code.

Answer (score 0):

if status is a string you need to encapsulate it like this:

```
display +="onClick=\"Apply('"+ Status +"');\" ";
```

Note the different usage of single and double quotes

Answer (score 0):

If you Status is string you have to use "" for example "String". In your case this should work:

```
display +="<td><input type'button' onClick='Apply("'+Status+'");' value='Apply'/></td>";
```

Number works because they dont need apostrophe and thats why they are processed correctly.

I made simplier example and used your code to show it. Check your JavaScript console to see a result:
http://jsfiddle.net/EE8hN/

Answer (score 0):

check this one.this wil work

display += `'<td><input type="button" onClick="Apply('+status+')" value="Apply"/></td>'`

Answer (score 0):

```
function querySuccess(tx, results, Type, Status, Amount, Years){
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var display = document.createElement('table');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var tmpEl;

    var tmpTr = tr.cloneNode();
    var tmpTd = td.cloneNode();
    tmpTd.textContent = "First Year Rate";
    tmpTr.appendChild(tmpTd);
    tmpTd = td.cloneNode();
    tmpTd.textContent = "Apply Now";
    tmpTr.appendChild(tmpTd);

    display.appendChild(tmpTr);

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        tmpTr = tr.cloneNode();
        tmpTd = td.cloneNode();
        tmpTd.textContent = result.rows.item[i].first_year;
        tmpTr.appendChild(tmpTd);
        tmpEl = document.createElement('input');
        tmpEl.type = 'button';
        tmpEl.value = 'Apply';
        tmpEl.onclick = Apply; // yeah, just like this
        tmpTd = td.cloneNode();
        tmpTd.appendChild(tmpEl);
        tmpTr.appendChild(tmpTd);
    }

}
```